# WooCommerce Display Products on Hover

Tags: php, woocommerce, custom-taxonomy, jquery-hover, mousehover

I have this code that outputs products from my category which I have taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50802271/display-products-from-specific-product-category-in-woocommerce)

I have created a dropdown navigation, how can I display the products for each category once I hover over the category link using the php code to query my 8 products.

HTML for Dropdown

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
.dropbtn {
  background-color: #04AA6D;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {display: block;}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {background-color: #3e8e41;}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Hoverable Dropdown</h2>
<p>Move the mouse over the button to open the dropdown menu.</p>

<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Computers</a>
    <a href="#">Televisions</a>
    <a href="#">Phones</a>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Example PHP output for category: computers

```
 <?php

// Here set your product category SLUG (can be multiple coma separated)
$product_categories = array('computers');

$wc_query = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => 5,
    'tax_query' => array( array(
        'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
        'field'    => 'slug',
        'terms'    => $product_categories,
        'operator' => 'IN',
    ) )
) );
?>
<ul>
     <?php if ($wc_query->have_posts()) : ?>
     <?php while ($wc_query->have_posts()) :
                $wc_query->the_post(); ?>
     <li>
          <h3>
               <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
               <?php the_title(); ?>
               </a>
          </h3>
          <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
          <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
     </li>
     <?php endwhile; ?>
     <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
     <?php else:  ?>
     <li>
          <?php _e( 'No Products' ); ?>
     </li>
     <?php endif; ?>
</ul>
```